# How to make an image of Ubuntu Server installation using VMware Tools/Player?

Tags: ubuntu, images, vmware-player, ubuntu-server

I was asked to provide an image of my Ubuntu Server 9.10 with LAMP made by VMware Player for setting up a VPS. Most of the information on the internet is about Ubuntu Desktop and Windows, so I am a bit confused.

Could you explain me how I can do that?

Note: I am very beginner so kindly ask you to provide me step-by-step commands to execute in the Ubuntu Server command-line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get a [ubuntu server disk imag](http://www.ubuntu.com/products/whatisubuntu/serveredition)e (this is different from the desktop version). select this as your cd rom device in vmware player, do an install. [Select LAMP server in tasksel or select individual pakages post install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP). That's pretty much it for a basic lamp server VM

Comment: As I understand, I need to have Ubuntu Desktop on one partition in which I can run VMware Player for installing Ubuntu Server to another partition. Is it correct? Initially I thought that the image will be created from Ubuntu Server after installing the player on it.

Comment: you can run VMware player in ubuntu, or windows, or another linux distro- i'd suggest installing vmware player, and reading the docs, and generally poking around with it first. its a fairly simple gui. Once Vmware player is set up, its about identical to setting up a real system.

Answer (score 1):

The work may already have been done for you:

[VMWare's Virtual Applicances](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/cat/0?k=ubuntu+lamp&c=0) (link goes to ubuntu+lamp search)

If you want to image an existing installation then VMWare's free [Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) may help

Comment: Thanks for your tip! However, by security considerations, I would like to make an image by myself. Plus, I can define some initial settings of my webserver. (I will not be provided a command-shell access)

Answer (score 1):

I found this which seems pretty nice. A Turnkey solution: http://www.turnkeylinux.org/lamp